# python loop prints too high/too low/ else

Tags: python, loops

hello im having a issue with this loop printing "too high or too low" or prints else endlessly, and not letting me to try the number guessing game that i need to do for the school assignment.

````
choice=int(input('pick a maximum number:'))

max_value=int(choice) #defines max_value

import random
rand_num=random.randint(1,max_value)

playerguess=int(input('guess a number:')) #it had to be int(input) so it can be numberized, same as the rest of the loop

counter=0

while counter<=10:
    counter+=1
    if counter==10:
        print('too many guesses try again')
        break
    
    if playerguess>rand_num:
        int(input('too high, try again:'))

    if playerguess<rand_num:
        int(input('too low try again:'))

    elif rand_num==playerguess:
        print('Congratations you got it in', counter, 'guesses')
        break

    else:
        playerguess=print('something went wrong try to fix the code')
        break

#guess had to be input so that it can loop again. its still a test tho, might need adjustments

#loop half working but prints(else) too often to make any sense, or is trapped in "too high/too low" loop

#Limit inputed so it doesnt repeat endlessly successfully```
````

Comment: you don't assign the user input to the object `playerguess`, it should be `playerguess=int(input('too high, try again:'))` for all `input()`

Comment: Also you can change `playerguess=print(...` to just `print(...` as the current code assigns `print()` output (equal to `None`) to `playerguess`. You probably don't want to do that

Comment: The `int` in `max_value=int(choice)` is pointless since the line just above it defines `choice` to be an int. It also seems pointless to have two names for the exact same quantity. What is the point of your variable `choice`? Why not just use `max_value = int(input('pick a maximum number:'))` in the first line?

Comment: its so that it can be numberizied for the number guessing game. also it would try to do math when its not supposed to, and class 'int' error comes up.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia i tried to fix the inputs inside the loop and it comes back as else in the second loop. its supposed to let me continue guessing until it runs out or i got it right.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if playerguess<rand_num:
```

should be

```
    elif playerguess<rand_num:
```

Otherwise, if the guess is greater than the target, then both
`if playerguess>rand_num:` and the `else:` cases will be run.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "continue" method if you want:

```
max_value=int(input('pick a maximum number: '))

rand_num=random.randint(1,max_value)

counter=0

while counter<=10:
    playerguess=int(input('guess a number:'))
    counter+=1
    if counter==10:
        print('too many guesses try again')
        break
    
    if playerguess<rand_num:
        print("too low try again")
        continue
    if playerguess>rand_num:
        print("too high try again")
        continue
    elif rand_num==playerguess:
        print('Congratations you got it in', counter, 'guesses')
        break
```

Comment: or you can use a function to do that if you want

Comment: pick a maximum number: 44
guess a number:23
too low try again
guess a number:21
Congratations you got it in 2 guesses
 - That can't be right...

Comment: it was a problem using "<" and ">", I edited it.